# Missing Spaces When Inserted Element is Rendered in DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom, nodes

I'm getting some really strange behavior from a Third-Party vendor's platform. I have HTML content in the form of a string and I'm trying to replace an HTML element or Node (don't really care which) in the DOM with an HTML element created from that string. Either way I do it, the content of the element/node changes AFTER I put it into the DOM. It's small stuff, like missing spaces (regular and non-breaking). As a matter of fact, it might exclusively be missing spaces...

Below I've included a sample of of what I'm trying to put into the DOM and what I'm getting out as a result.

**Before Insertion:**

```
<span style="font-size: 12px;">Si tiene alguna pregunta sobre la información provista, llame a <strong>la sala de partos</strong>, al teléfono <strong><span style="color: rgb(149, 55, 52);">(650) 723-5403</span></strong>.</span>
```

**Once In DOM:**

```
<span style="font-size: 12px;">Si tiene alguna pregunta sobre la información provista, llame a<strong>la sala de partos</strong>, al teléfono<strong><span style="color: rgb(149, 55, 52);">(650) 723-5403</span></strong>.</span>
```

If you look closely, there is a missing space before each STRONG tag. It also seems to be removing spaces after STRONG tags (not included in the example provided above). I don't get it! It's happening in Chrome, Edge, and Firefox. Does it have something to do with how I'm turning and HTML string into an HTML element? But that's the thing, the HTML element (or Node) includes the spaces prior to insertion into the DOM, but not after.

I'm a hair's breadth (hare's breath?) from adding CSS margins to all of the STRONG tags, but I'd prefer to do things "the right way" if at all possible. Does anyone have any idea where my missing spaces have gone?

I've tried setting the outerHTML of the target element equal to the htmlText. I've tried instantiating the htmlText and then doing a replaceChild in the target's parent. I've even tried creating a wrapper, instantiating htmlText and then replacing the target's innerHTML with the innerHTML of the instantiated element.

```
target.outerHTML = htmlText;
```

```
let wrapper = document.createElement("DIV");
wrapper.innerHTML = htmlText;
let newElement = wrapper.firstChild;
target.parentNode.replaceChild(newElement,target);
```

```
let wrapper = document.createElement("DIV");
wrapper.innerHTML = htmlText;
target.innerHTML = wrapper.firstChild.innerHTML; 
target.classList.remove("triggerAttribute");
```

Same result every time, missing spaces, both breaking and non-breaking, usually (perhaps always?) before or after a STRONG tag.

Comment: Please post the code that creates `htmlText` from the original text.

Comment: The htmlText variable is just stored as a string. Nothing is "creating" it. That being said, here is the portion of the htmlText show above copied directly from the original htmlText string before being instantiated or placed into the DOM:  <span style="font-size: 12px;">Si tiene alguna pregunta sobre la información provista, llame a <strong>la sala de partos</strong>, al teléfono <strong><span style="color: rgb(149, 55, 52);">(650) 723-5403</span></strong>.</span>

Comment: Wait, sorry, looks like I misread your comment... The htmlText variable IS the original text.

Comment: I misunderstood, I thought you were modifying the original text by inserting `<strong>` into it.

Comment: I can't reproduce it: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/21h9bLg6/

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: Hmmmmm... Yeah, I'm not able to reproduce it in jsfiddle either. Also, the website I'm having a problem with, input the string and perform the same manipulations via the console, then it works just fine. And the string that I'm using as the input is the same as the one that my script is using, I'm just logging it to the console and doing a copy paste.

Comment: There must be something more going on that you haven't shown. Unless we can see it in action, we can't help you fix it.

Comment: @ Barmar, I totally agree. I can't replicate it anywhere except where I'm having the problem...

Comment: Is there a public link to the place with the problem?

Comment: @Barmar, Not easily... Everything is behind a paywall. However, I just tried something stupid where I saved both my original text string and the element I inserted into the DOM to the window. Then, I triggered a function that checked the element's outerHTML against the text string and if it found any differences, it would do the same insertion. the original script had performed. And the missing spaces are back. The delayed insertion leaves the spaces while the initial insertion doesn't.

Comment: So, I still have no idea what the heck is going on, but hacky as it is, here's what ended up working. If I do the insertion or target.outerHTML = htmlText as part of a setTimeout (even if the delay is only 1ms), then it works fine. However, if there is more than 1 target element on the page, since I'm iterating through an array, then bad things happen, so I end up having to save the text and the target element to the window before triggering the insertion of the new element.

Comment: There MUST be some other code in your application that's removing the spaces. Somehow the delayed assignment is bypassing that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252266/discussion-between-thor-and-barmar).

Answer (score 0):

Barmar is correct, there must be something else, in some other function, that's stripping out the spaces. Until I find that, this is what works :-(

let contentID = target.getAttribute('data-ijcontent');

window[contentID] = {
text:htmlText,
element:target
}

setTimeout(function(){window[contentID].element.outerHTML = window[contentID].text;delete window[contentID];},1)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to reproduce from the description only, but I had a similar issue the other day regarding `<a>`-tags inside a `<span>`. When placed inside the `<span>`, the whitespace before and after the `<a>`-tags were gone.
When I inspected the element, I noticed the style was set to `display: inline-flex;`

I changed the spans style to `display: inline-block;` and that solved the whole issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).